# having Live Server (vscode) Error while opening in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, browser, liveserver

In vs code everything is fine. While clicking on the GO live button(for HTML CSS files) and its showing port:5500 but when the chrome browser opens after some seconds loading it saying its taking too long to respond This site cant be reached ERROR how to fix it is really a headache for me [this is the screen snip of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WClEW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before , at first i just ignored the live server extension and i opened my html files directly from the folder . But after , i did a Restart to the extension host and it worked perfectly again .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in the code causing infinite loop and hence crashing. I believe my solution can help with this perfectly. Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73500337/while-running-vs-code-live-server-go-live-the-browser-is-crashing-i-am-using)!