# While running VS Code Live Server (Go Live), the browser is crashing. I am using Google Chrome as default

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, visual-studio-code

While running VS Code Live Server (Go Live), the **browser is crashing** with the below mentioned error.  I am using Google Chrome as default.  I re-installed VS Code after uninstalling completely (from cache even), restarted browser, and then restarted PC as well with no use.  When I checked "Use Local Ip" in LiveServer>Settings:, server is **taking too long to respond** and eventually fails to load the page (Error:  "**This site can't be reached**").  Another important thing is that Chrome is opening every other website properly.  This problem exists only when opening VS Code Live Server. Below is the error code:

Chrome Browser Error:
"**Aw, Snap!
Something went wrong while displaying this webpage.
Error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT**"

Another popup is also showing up simultaneously:
"**DevTools was disconnected from the page.
Once page is reloaded, DevTools will automatically reconnect.**"

(This didn't seem like a bug in the code of script.js)

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution:

Indeed it is a bug in the code of script.js.
**If you are having exactly the same problem as I described**, let us first see what we don't need to do, as I found these suggestions everywhere, and none will work when both VS Code and your browser are perfectly fine (they only appear to be not working):

1. No need to restart or reinstall VS Code.
2. No need to restart or reinstall browser.
3. No need to restart the PC
4. No need to disable browser extensions or VS Code extensions.
5. No need to change LiveServer Custom Browser; you can keep it
   default.
6. No need to change LiveServer>Settings>Use local ip or Use browser
   preview (you can keep them both unchecked if they are already
   unchecked by default)

However, if you use firefox, console shows the error: "**Uncaught out of memory**"

Here, I got the first hint.  Firefox at least told me to look at memory, but it is not about the memory we think.  It is not about multiple tabs opened, lack of disk space, unstable disk, etc.  **It is the accidentally generated infinite loop in the code which is causing the memory problem** (check your code carefully to find it).
***In my case, I accidentally didn't tell it to execute the next iteration (i.e., missing counter update, increment, i++) and it is stuck in the same while loop forever, as the condition is satisfied forever without any counter update***.

After fixing the code, the below error might show up in the console.  Just refresh the page and it will go away.
"**favicon.ico:1  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**"

**Note:**  Unless you fix the code or comment it out, other linked files (like .html) in the folder wouldn't work either.